# How to consume WCF soap web service in node.js

Tags: wcf, node.js, soap

I tried lot of examples available in the net using node module wcf.js. But could not get any appropriate result. I'm using the below url

> https://webservice.kareo.com/services/soap/2.1/KareoServices.svc?wsdl

Any one who can explain me with the help of code will be really helpful. I want to know how to access the wsdl in node.js

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js: how to consume SOAP XML web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655252/node-js-how-to-consume-soap-xml-web-service)

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at [wcf.js](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/379389/Wcf-js-Call-WCF-web-services-from-Node-js/%20%22)

In short you can follow these steps:

1. npm install wcf.js
2. Write your code like this:

code

```
var Proxy = require('wcf.js').Proxy; 
var BasicHttpBinding = require('wcf.js').BasicHttpBinding; 

var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

//Ensure the proxy variable created below has a working wsdl link that actually loads wsdl    
var proxy = new Proxy(binding, "http://YourHost/YourService.svc?wsdl");

/*Ensure your message below looks like a valid working SOAP UI request*/
var message = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:sil='http://YourNamespace'>" +
                "<soapenv:Header/>" +
                "<soapenv:Body>" +
                "<sil:YourMethod>" +
                "<sil:YourParameter1>83015348-b9dc-41e5-afe2-85e19d3703f9</sil:YourParameter1>" +
                "<sil:YourParameter2>IMUT</sil:YourParameter2>" +
                "</sil:YourMethod>" +
                "</soapenv:Body>" +
                "</soapenv:Envelope>";
/*The message that you created above, ensure it works properly in SOAP UI rather copy a working request from SOAP UI*/

/*proxy.send's second argument is the soap action; you can find the soap action in your wsdl*/
proxy.send(message, "http://YourNamespace/IYourService/YourMethod", function (response, ctx) {
    console.log(response);
    /*Your response is in xml and which can either be used as it is of you can parse it to JSON etc.....*/
});
```

Comment: This is not working for https protocol. :(
How to call https service?

Answer (score 1):

I think that an alternative would be to:

- use a tool such as [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) to record input and output xml messages
- use [node request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to form input xml message to send (POST) the request to the web service (note that standard javascript templating mechanisms such as [ejs](http://embeddedjs.com/) or [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) could help you here) and finally
- use an XML parser to deserialize response data to JavaScript objects

Yes, this is a rather dirty and low level approach but it should work without problems

Answer (score 1):

You don't have that many options.

You'll probably want to use one of:

- node-soap
- douche
- soapjs

i tried node-soap to get INR USD rate with following code.

```
app.get('/getcurr', function(req, res) {
var soap = require('soap');
var args = {FromCurrency: 'USD', ToCurrency: 'INR'};
var url = "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL";
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.ConversionRate(args, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Code Project has got a [neat sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/379389/Wcf-js-Call-WCF-web-services-from-Node-js) which uses [wcf.js](https://github.com/yaronn/wcf.js) for which api's are wcf like so no need to learn new paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use one of:

- [node-soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap)
- [douche](https://github.com/kr1sp1n/douche)
- [soapjs](https://github.com/jmoyers/soapjs)

Aslo, there's [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655252/node-js-how-to-consume-soap-xml-web-service).

Comment: U can have look at my code in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562943/wcf-web-service-in-node-js but it throws some error. Can u plz help me in whats wrong in code?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap. By default `forceSoap12Headers` option was set to `false` which prevented `node-soap` to generate correct soap message according to SOAP 1.2. Check for more details: [I am confused about SOAP namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403980/i-am-confused-about-soap-namespaces). After I set it to `true`, I was able to make a call to .NET WCF service. Here is a TypeScript code snipper that worked for me.

```
import * as soap from 'soap';
import { IOptions } from 'soap';

// ...

const url = 'https://www.your-domain.com/stock.svc?wsdl';
const opt: IOptions = {
  forceSoap12Headers: true,
};

soap.createClient(url, opt, (err, client: soap.Client) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  const wsSecurityOptions = {
    hasTimeStamp: false,
  };

  const wsSecurity = new soap.WSSecurity('username', 'password', wsSecurityOptions);
  client.setSecurity(wsSecurity);
  client.addSoapHeader({ Action: 'http://tempuri.org/API/GetStockDetail' }, undefined, 'wsa', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing');
  client.addSoapHeader({ To: 'https://www.your-domain.com/stock.svc' }, undefined, 'wsa', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing');

  const args = {
    symbol: 'GOOG',
  };

  client.GetStockDetail(
    args,
    (requestErr, result) => {
      if (requestErr) {
        throw requestErr;
      }

      console.log(result);
    },
  );
});
```

Here couple links to the documentation of `node-soap` usage:

1. https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/tree/master/test
2. https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap