# Consume WCF service using Node.js

Tags: node.js, wcf

I am consuming my WCF service using Node.js. I am using WCF.js package.
I am able to communicate with the service but not able to fetch data.
I am getting the response action method in response.

I have tried WCF.js package.

Following is the code that i tried

```
var result;
var BasicHttpBinding = require('wcf.js').BasicHttpBinding
  , Proxy = require('wcf.js').Proxy
  , binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
  , proxy = new Proxy(binding, " http://domain:port/myservice.svc")
  , message = '<Envelope xmlns=' +
            '"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                 '<Header />' +
                   '<Body>' +
                     '<GetConnections xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>' +
                    '</Body>' +
               '</Envelope>'

proxy.send(message, "http://tempuri.org/IMyInterface/GetConnections", function(result, ctx) {
  console.log(result)
});
```

I am getting following response

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <ActivityId CorrelationId="ba0b223b-a823-47ff-826d-467d595f0bc7"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">47ff68ec-2083-417f-b29d-52571c4cd153
        </ActivityId>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <GetConnectionsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetConnectionsResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/vRanger.API.Types.Common" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        </GetConnectionsResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I want the data to be returned.
Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t get your point, this xml response is the returned result. What is the data?  If you want to parse XML document, we could use the below JavaScript DOMParser.
[Parse XML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML
In addition, it seems that the result is empty in the GetConnectinResult node.

```
<GetConnectionsResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/vRanger.API.Types.Common" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

If the GetConnections method has the returned result, there might be some parameters in the method signature.  Thereby we need to add the value of the parameter.

```
 "<GetConnections xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>" +
   "<value>123</value>" +
 "</GetConnections>" +
```

At last, I do not see the library's support for complex data types, where the result returned is a custom object.
https://github.com/yaronn/wcf.js
Please try the below link.
[How to consume WCF soap web service in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612251/how-to-consume-wcf-soap-web-service-in-node-js)

Comment: Thanks abraham for the response. The issue was with my request message xml. Rectified the same.